# Not able to update the status of the App correctly in Kubernetes Operator

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

Based on the example and documentation from https://github.com/nokia/industrial-application-framework/tree/main/consul-operator, I was trying to create a sample Kubernetes application managed by Kubernetes Operator; (used Kubebuilder) code here https://github.com/alexcpn/go_operator_2022/

Since `AppStatus` field is mandatory; I am updating this after checking in my operator logic if Pods created by my Operator (that's all that this operator does- creates a deployment based on the image given in the CR) are running

Code snippet

```
    if runningStatus == true { //update the status
        testOperator.Status.CommonStatus.Healthy = true
        testOperator.Status.CommonStatus.Phase = "Running" //TODO not setting properly
        log.Log.Info("Test", "Going to update Test Operator Status", testOperator.Status)
        // FOR APPFW
        testOperator.Status.AppStatus = nokiaappfw.AppStatusRunning
        testOperator.SetAppStatus(nokiaappfw.AppStatusRunning)
        if err := r.Status().Update(ctx, &testOperator); err != nil {
            log.Log.Error(err, "unable to update TestOperator status")
            return ctrl.Result{}, err
        } else {
            log.Log.Info("Test", "Updated Test Operator Status", testOperator.Status)
        }
    }
```

Output of `make run`. Note that it is not setting the field in the else part. Is it because I am running this in `make run` against the cluster and not as an image inside the cluster ?

Full changes here https://github.com/alexcpn/go_operator_2022/pull/2/files

```
1.6613427667224455e+09  INFO    Pod Image is    {"controller": "testoperartor", "controllerGroup": "grpcapp.mytest.io", "controllerKind": "Testoperartor", "testoperartor": {"name":"testoperartor-sample","namespace":"default"}, "namespace": "default", "name": "testoperartor-sample", "reconcileID": "9a810d32-c3ec-4680-8bf4-6c4e8ae3850d", "PodImageName": "alexcpn/run_server:1.2"}
1.6613427667224557e+09  INFO    Pod Image is set        {"PodImageName": "alexcpn/run_server:1.2"}
1.6613427668227704e+09  INFO    Deployment Already  exists      {"testoperartor-sample-deployment": "Namespace", "default": "ok"}
1.6613427669230652e+09  INFO    Pod Name        {"": "testoperartor-sample-deployment-55645ff5cb-hpzrm", "Pod Status": "Running"}
1.661342766923107e+09   INFO    Test    {"Going to update Test Operator Status": {"CommonStatus":{"healthy":true,"phase":"Running"}}}
1.6613427669270532e+09  INFO    Test    {"Updated Test Operator Status": {"CommonStatus":{"healthy":false}}}
```

Types file

```
// TestoperartorStatus defines the observed state of Testoperartor
type TestoperartorStatus struct {
    // INSERT ADDITIONAL STATUS FIELD - define observed state of cluster
    // Important: Run "make" to regenerate code after modifying this file
    addonv1alpha1.CommonStatus `json:"CommonStatus,omitempty"`
    nokiaappfw.AppStatus       `json:"AppStatus,omitempty"` //FOR NOKIAAPPFMW
}
```